# Share multiple log files from multiple servers with multiple users

Tags: logging

I need help finding a tool or application that can be used to share multiple log files from multiple servers with multiple users. Now we are doing it by adding all the log folders of the servers by NFS and Samba on a single server, and giving users access through samba to that centralized server. This is quite inefficient, because we already have more than 200 shared folders attached to the server and it gets slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of logs use have (OS logs, App logs, some service logs)? What OS you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually what most people do once their server park starts to grow is a move away from inspecting log files. They consolidate all log data in a “big data” solution  and add a (typically web based) front end where all applicable users can log into to visualize and search that data.

Products are for example Splunk, ELK stack (elastic search , log stash and Kibana), Graylog and many others.

Some applications can be configured to send their log events directly to the products above, for those that can’t such products come with log shipping agents that will ingest your existing log files.

You can then use standard dashboards, create your own , add alerts, search for specific events and more easily make correlations between events registered in different servers and parts of your landscape